# Split string adding extra string when no data is there

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string, split

I have some code that splits a session into strings by a `-`

My session looks something like this `123-456-789-` and I split it like this

```
Dim MyString As String() = Session("MySession").Split("-"C)
```

And i've got a some code like this

```
Dim x as Integer

For x = 0 to MyString - 1

Response.write("Ref: " & MyString(x) & "<br>")

Next
```

This writes the code like this

```
Ref: 123
Ref: 456
Ref: 789
Ref:
```

So it's adding an extra Ref where it shouldn't be because there is no data after the last `-`

Is there a way to stop this adding in the extra one?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [String.Split(String[], StringSplitOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) method, with [StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx) as second param.